# python - calling plt.figure prevents Checkbutton from update - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, matplotlib

A GUI that works with different pages, one is a graph page using the animate function, and a second page should start a guide, the guide will depend on what you click in a checkbutton. I have created a post because I thought I was the checkbutton that was not well defined, but now i found that calling the f=plt.figure() is prevent the upgrade of the checkbutton.

See this code works for the Checkbutton: - Before the animate function .. But then the graphic update on the other page does not work since f is not defined in the animate function. If i put the animate function and f definition in the PageThree (GRAPHIC page) the update of the figure fails. 
But when i allow the f=plt.figure()  , graphic is fine, but checkbutton stays False all the time...

```
import matplotlib
from tkinter import *
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import *
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
import subprocess
import csv
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from os import startfile
from time import time

LARGE_FONT = ("Times", 11, "bold italic")
NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 9)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica",7)
HELP_FONT=("Times", 9 , "bold")


pullDataMS=pd.read_table("test.raw.spectrum_table.tsv", header=1)
LevelMS=pullDataMS.groupby('msLevel')

rt=pullDataMS['rt']
TIC=pullDataMS['TIC']

MS1=LevelMS.get_group('ms1')
MS2=LevelMS.get_group('ms2')

### THIS CALL overplots the update? -.- ###
#f = plt.figure(facecolor="white")**

 ######################
def animate (i):
     pullData=pd.read_table("InstrumentPerformance.txt", parse_dates=True,
                       dayfirst=True, index_col=1)
     Names_In = ['Q1','Q2','Q3']

     Inst=pullData.groupby('Instrument')

     a = f.add_subplot(2,3,1)
     a2 = f.add_subplot(2,3,2, sharex=a)
     a3=f.add_subplot(2,3,3)
     a4=f.add_subplot(2,3,4)
     a5=f.add_subplot(2,3,5)
     a7=f.add_subplot(2,6,11)
     f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.29)
     a.clear()
     a2.clear()
     a3.clear()
     a4.clear()
     a5.clear()
     a7.clear()
     for Name in Names_In:
          Q=Inst.get_group(Name)
          y=Q['MS/MS recorded']
          x=Q['Identified peptides']

          a.plot(x, "o",label='['+Name+"]")
          a.plot(x, 'k-', lw=0.7, label='_nolegend_')

          a2.plot(y, 'o',label='['+Name+']')
          a2.plot(y, 'k-', label='_nolegend_', lw=0.7)

          a.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(5))
          a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d-%m-%Y"))
          a.set_ylabel('# of unique peptide sequences')
          a2.set_ylabel('# of MS/MS spectra')
          a.legend(loc='upper left',fancybox=True, numpoints=1, shadow=True,prop={'size':9})
          a2.legend(loc='upper left',fancybox=True, numpoints=1, shadow=True,prop={'size':9})
          a.set_xlim(np.array([-20,20])+a.get_xlim())
          a.set_ylim(np.array([0,2000])+a.get_ylim())
          a2.set_xlim(np.array([-20,20])+a.get_xlim())
          a2.set_ylim(np.array([0,5000])+a.get_ylim())




class PAL3_guide(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

          tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
          container = tk.Frame(self)
          container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
          container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
          self.frames = {}

          for F in (StartPage,Tut01,PageThree):

               frame = F(container, self)

               self.frames[F] = frame

               frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

          self.show_frame(StartPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):
          frame=self.frames[cont]
          frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self,parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, background="white")
          button_PAL = ttk.Button(self, text="Setup Guide", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Tut01))
          button_PAL.pack()
          button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page 1", 
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
          button2.pack()

class Tut01(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self,parent,controller):


          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)       
          self.parent=parent

          self.initUI()

     def initUI(self):
          self.var=BooleanVar()
          cb=Checkbutton(self,text="show", variable=self.var, command=self.onClick)
          cb.select()
          cb.place(x=50,y=50)
     def onClick(self):
          if self.var.get()== True:
               print("hi")
          else:
               print("buh")

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self,parent,controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
          label = tk.Label(self, text="GraphPage", font=LARGE_FONT)
          label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
          button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
          button1.pack()


          canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
          canvas.show()
          canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

          toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,self)
          toolbar.update()
          canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


app = PAL3_guide()
app.geometry("1280x920")
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=10000)  

app.mainloop()
```

**EDIT FOR MIXONE**: yes i have tried to do something like :

```
def animate (f):
     pullData=pd.read_table("InstrumentPerformance.txt", parse_dates=True,
                       dayfirst=True, index_col=1)
     Names_In = ['Q1','Q2','Q3']

     Inst=pullData.groupby('Instrument')

     a = f.add_subplot(2,3,1)
     a2 = f.add_subplot(2,3,2, sharex=a)...
```

...
and:

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self,parent,controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
          label = tk.Label(self, text="GraphPage", font=LARGE_FONT)
          label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
          button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
          button1.pack()

          f=plt.figure()

          ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate(f), interval=10000)  

          canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
          canvas.show()
          canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

          #toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,self)
          #toolbar.update()
          #canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


app = PAL3_guide()
app.geometry("1280x920")

app.mainloop()
```

In this case the Checkbutton works, but the figure is not updated but it is plotted in the beginning.

Comment: Same error as on your other question, which I thinks is what you started this with no?
Also, I see nowhere that f is set to something. Be carefull that when you do set it, it is not just being set locally inside a function

Comment: My bad, I see that you put it inside a comment

Comment: Have you tried just setting f as a parameter for the animate function?

Comment: I guess so, see edit of the question.